# nonblocking socket recv problem while using it with epoll

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nonblocking, epollet

i've got a problem: sometimes (not regularly) recv returns `-1` and `errno == EAGAIN` while using `epoll` in `edge-triggered` mode. piece of code:

```
server_sock = startup(&port);

if ( (epollfd = epoll_create(4096)) < 0) {
    perror("epoll_create error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
ev.data.fd = server_sock;
if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, server_sock, &ev) == -1) {
    perror("epoll_ctl: server_sock");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (1) {
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, 4096, -1);
    if (nfds == -1) {
        perror("epoll_wait");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
        if (events[i].data.fd == server_sock) {
            client_sock = accept(server_sock,
                         (struct sockaddr *)&client_name,
                         (socklen_t *)(&client_name_len));

        if (client_sock == -1) //server overloaded
            continue;

        if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
            std::cout << "EPOLLIN on " << client_sock << std::endl;
        }

        Arch::set_nonblocking(client_sock);
        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLET; //input data and connection closing
        ev.data.fd = client_sock;

        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_sock, &ev) == -1) {
            perror("epoll_ctl: client_socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        accept_request(client_sock);

        } else {
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) {
                epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &ev);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`startup(&port)` creates nonblocking socket, binding with port and so on. my script sends following data:
`GET /connect?id=1&secret=1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` but sometimes `recv` return `-1` in this function (calling inside of `accept_request`) :

```
/**********************************************************************/
/* Get a line from a socket, whether the line ends in a newline,
 * carriage return, or a CRLF combination.  Terminates the string read
 * with a null character.  If no newline indicator is found before the
 * end of the buffer, the string is terminated with a null.  If any of
 * the above three line terminators is read, the last character of the
 * string will be a linefeed and the string will be terminated with a
 * null character.
 * Parameters: the socket descriptor
 *             the buffer to save the data in
 *             the size of the buffer
 * Returns: the number of bytes stored (excluding null) */
/**********************************************************************/
int get_line(int sock, char *buf, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    char c = '\0';
    int n;

    while ((i < size - 1) && (c != '\n')) {
        n = recv(sock, &c, 1, 0);
        //debug
        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
        if (n > 0) {
            if (c == '\r') {
                n = recv(sock, &c, 1, MSG_PEEK);
                if ((n > 0) && (c == '\n'))
                    recv(sock, &c, 1, 0);
                else
                    c = '\n';
            }
            buf[i] = c;
            i++;
        } else {
            //debug
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
                std::cout << "EWOULDBLOCK" << std::endl;
            c = '\n';
        }
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';

    return(i);
}
```

as epoll man page wrote i have to read/write until i get `EAGAIN`, but i got it already! and i sure the buffer don't be empty. what i do wrong?

**UPD:** i've found out an interesting thing: when such situation is happened i use in my code `sleep(1)` and `recc(...)` again and i get data that i expect! it's a dirty trick. is there any more graceful approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely normal for the first `recv()` in that case to return `EAGAIN`.  `epoll()` never told you if it was readable yet or not.

*Every single* `recv()` should be prepared to handle `EAGAIN` if you are using non-blocking sockets.  Spurious wakeups are possible, so whenever an API like `select()`, `poll()` or `epoll()` tells you that a socket is readable, it's only saying "it *might* be readable - give it a try".

Comment: but in that moment when `epoll_wait` returns i certainly know there data (`GET /connect?id=1&secret=1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`) in buffer. in that case why `recv` returns `EAGAIN` and what i have to do to process it properly?

Comment: @milo: No.  `epoll_wait()` only told you that there was a new socket to `accept()` - it did *not* tell you that there was data to read from the new socket.  If `recv()` returns `EAGAIN` you either 1) process what data you've got already or 2) go back to `epoll_wait()` and wait some more.

Comment: if 1) i cannot process any data... so if 2) i will return to `epoll_wait` i'll lose my data. right?

Comment: @milo: You won't lose any data, unless you specifically throw it away.  Until the data has been handed to you by `recv()`, the OS will hold on to it.